# Joomla Virtuemart Changing Manufacturer SEF

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I want to change the sef created by virtuemart for manufacturer.How can I do that?

This URL : http://demo.com/index.php/manufacturer/demo

To This : http://demo.com/index.php/myowntext/demo

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change strings in \components\com_virtuemart\language\en-GB\en-GB.com_virtuemart.sef.ini
**COM_VIRTUEMART_SEF_MANUFACTURER**="myowntext"
**COM_VIRTUEMART_SEF_MANUFACTURERS**="myowntext"

Virtuemart->Configuration->Seo
Must be enabled the option "Translate Strings"

if it did not work: 
Change strings strings in \language\your_language\your_language.com_virtuemart.sef.ini:
**COM_VIRTUEMART_SEF_MANUFACTURER**="myowntext"
**COM_VIRTUEMART_SEF_MANUFACTURERS**="myowntext"